# M/M/1 queue derivation: how to "recursively solve in dependence on $p_0$"

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, queueing-theory

I want to sketch out the derivation of the equations for an M/M/1 queue for a presentation I'm giving.

I can understand most of the derivation from [Willig](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.136.9734&rep=rep1&type=pdf) but I don't understand this section from p10 well enough.

Is there a more fleshed out explanation of this?

[image: section from p10 of Willig paper]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the first displayed equation to find $p_1$ in terms of $p_0$. Substitute for $p_1$ in the second equation. Then you  can find $p_2$ in terms  of $p_0$. Do a few more and you can see the pattern, and show it to your audience at the presentation.

Comment: Oh awesome! That works great. Many thanks.